# GWT equivalent of Smart-GWT's Live Grid

Tags: ajax, gwt, grid, smartgwt

Is there a GWT equivalent for SmartGWT's Live Grid with the Async loading of scrolled data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there's no sufficient equivalent for rich grids in GWT, let alone Ajax driven grid widgets.

One appropriate alternative would be [GXT's live grid](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3alivegrid), but that's just going out of the frying pan into the fire, since you'd have to work with GXT instead of SmartGWT.

GWT was not meant to be used as a widget library, providing a vast selection of UI widgets, but merely supply a firm infrastructure for Java programmers to easily develop rich Ajax web applications. It can (and *should*) be extended with supplementary widget libraries to compensate for its lack thereof.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cell table, data Grid . hear is the showcase which has simple cell List example which is same as your requirement so you can apply same logic for cell table and you can create Live grid in GWT. hear is the link for cell List [Cell list Example GWT](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList)